# Initialise GitHub repo from RStudio without Using Command Line

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I have been tasked with testing the feasibility of a GitHub training programme in my place of work. Due to internal security, we cannot utilise the command line. I am attempting to:

- Initialise a new git repository
- Add files from my current R Project
- Commit these staged files
- Push to a newly created GitHub repo

All from RStudio using git2r functions.

Every tutorial I find online relies on the command line or looks at cloning EXISTING repositories. I cannot find any that walk through the creation of a repo from a local r project.

Workflow so far looks like this:

```
library(git2r)

repo <- init("C:/local_folder/r_project_folder")

config(repo, user.name, user.email)

cred <- cred_token() # Git PAT is included in the projects renviron file

add(repo, "*")

commit(repo, "Commit message")

push()
```

Returning the error message:

```
 Error in 'git2r_push': remote 'origin' does not exist
```

If there is simply a link to a comprehensive tutorial, that would help me. The git2r README focuses on connecting to existing repos.

Comment: Can't you create a repo then clone that repo to your local machine? Then from there since it's connected you can push straight to git. You don't have to use the command line, it just requires you to create the repo before messing with r.

Comment: I think you're confusing a little bit with git vs GitHub. You've got a git repo locally. Pushing means you're copying that repo and its history to some other platform, in this case the GitHub website. If there's no remote set up, there's nowhere to push it to. GitHub is one of several options for hosting and sharing repos but not synonymous with git

Comment: The book Happy Git with R has a chapter on this: https://happygitwithr.com/rstudio-git-github.html

Comment: Would it be correct to say that he could create a git repo through GitHub, copy that git repo to his local machine, add the files, and then push back to GitHub? Sorry, just trying to understand the exact terminology.

Comment: Camille - now I had come across this but, unfortunately, creating a GitHub repo in this manner requires a command line prompt which, as I mentioned, is disabled. Could I do as Hansel suggests and clone an existing empty repo into a new folder? Attempting to do this from an R project folder has failed with an error message that this is impossible due to the target not being 'empty'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using a bit of google and a bit of Hansel Palencias suggestion:

Start by creating an empty GitHub repository on your repo page then enter the following commands:

```
# Clone existing github repo using url and linking this to your project path
clone(url = "https://github.com/user/name_of_repo.git", local_path = "path")

setwd("path")

# Assign variable repo as current local repository
repo <- repository()

# Configure access rights with github username and profile
config(repo, user.name='user name', user.email='email address')

# Add a PAT in local renviron folder
edit_r_environ()

# Save PAT as cred token
cred <- cred_token()

# Stage changs to commit
add(repo, "file.R")
commit(repo, "Commit message")

# Push changes
push(repo, 'origin', 'refs/heads/master', credentials = cred)
```

Bit of a hack but solves the problem. Will attempt using remotes() command as suggested as a more effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is because you haven't provided a location for git to push to.

I think you're looking for the `remotes` command - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/git2r/versions/0.23.0/topics/remotes

You can supply a local folder path to this, it doesn't have to be a remote server.